# Non standard inheritance mapping with AutoMapper

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, inheritance, mapping, automapper

I have "table inheritance" in my DB (where descendants reference base with foreign key) and use Linq To Sql as my DAL:

```
[Table]
class Document {
    [Column]public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column]public int DocTypeID { get; set; }
    [Association]public Application Application { get; set; }
}

[Table]
class Application {
    [Column]public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column]public string AppType { get; set; }
    [Association]public Document Document {get;set}
}
```

Since L2S does not support multi-table inheritance `Application` is not inherited from `Document`. However, in my entity classes i do want inheritance:

```
class DocumentBase {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int DocTypeID { get; set; }
}

class MyApplication : DocumentBase {
    public string AppType { get; set; }
}
```

Now i'm creating the mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentBase>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Application, MyApplication>();
```

But AutoMapper complains about base properties in `MyApplication` not mapped. I don't want to duplicate base properties in `MyApplication` map (too many descendants from `DocumentBase`). I found few posts suggesting custom `ITypeConverter` but don't understand how to apply it to my scenario. What do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [solution](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/inheriting-base-type-mappings-with-automapper-extension/) which also suffers from `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` complaining about base properties not mapped but slightly modified it:

```
static void InheritMappingFromBaseType<S, D>(this IMappingExpression<S, D> mappingExpression)
    where S: Document
    where D: DocumentBase
{
    mappingExpression // add any other props of Document
        .ForMember(d => d.DocTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Document.DocTypeId);
}
```

Now it can be chained to each `DocumentBase` descendant map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Application, MyApplication>()
    .InheritMappingFromBaseType();
```

and `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` is happy.

Comment: Very interesting. I haven't seen this before

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that DocTypeId is not being mapped. Try this

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentBase>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Application, MyApplication>()
          .ForMember(d => d.DocTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Document.ID);
```

Edited after comment:

You could invoke the base mapper like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentBase>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Application, MyApplication>()
    .AfterMap((app, myApp) => Map<Document, DocumentBase>(app.Document, myApp);
```

Comment: Exactly! And i don't want to map all base props in every descendant (what if there are 12 props in DocumentBase and i have 8 classes inherited from it?) so i need some generic solution.

Comment: Thanks, it does work! However, Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() seems to be unaware of AfterMap() saying the base props aren't mapped :( And I cannot disable the validation as it's important part of the testing (way too many mappings in the project).

Comment: I see. Another way to make AssertConfigurationIsValid happy  would've been to explicitly ignore the base properties like this: Mapper.CreateMap<Application, MyApplication>().ForMember(d => d.DocTypeId, opt => opt.Ignore())    .AfterMap((app, myApp) => Map<Document, DocumentBase>(app.Document, myApp);